# Is there a way to fix all naming rule violations at once in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a C# class created by someone else whose properties are all in lower case. Visual Studio shows all these as warnings for *Naming Rule Violation*. It lets me fix them one by one, but I have not been able to find a way to change them in the entire document. Is it possible to do so **without ReSharper**?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i would like to know the answer, i have the same problem

Comment: Try looking for 'code cleanup' in visual studio. It might be able to apply the rule.